# Where Can I find events for a control in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm really new in Java and Netbeans. I want to create a very simple Java webapplication with a button on it to do some actions, for example on on-click event.

I have created a Java webapplication and drag a Button from (HTML/JSP code clips) in Pallete section on  jsp page.

I have some problems:

- Where can I write a code on On-Click event for this button? where can I finde the events for this button
- I cant see the Pallete at the right side of my IDE I must do it (Tools->Pallete)

I am comming from .Net world and I can do this job very simple in .Net world. How can I do this job hier?

thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the code, just double click on your button in the Design view, or else switch to the Source view.  If your button is called `myButton` then the method will be called `myButtonActionPerformed()`

Comment: the problem is, that I cant see Design view on the top, only source and history

Comment: Try looking under Events in the Properties panel.  No Design view may mean that you selected the wrong type of project initially.  Netbeans may think you are writing a console application, not a GUI application.  See if adding a GUI form helps.Otherwise save your code and start a new GUI project.